# basic playback with programmatically created windows media player

Tags: c++, windows, com, atl, windows-media-player

I was trying to *"just quickly integrate"* the Windows Media Player via COM to play single files from the local file system or http sources - but due to the sparse documentation and online resources to its usage when not embedding into some kind of an Ole container, i couldn't get that supposedly trivial use-case to work.

Initialization etc. works fine, but actually playing some file always fails.

Example code, starting with initialization (error handling stripped, basically translated from the [C# example at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd562692(VS.85).aspx), executed on the main thread):

```
CComPtr<IWMPPlayer> player;
player.CoCreateInstance(__uuidof(WindowsMediaPlayer), 0, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER);
CComQIPtr<IWMPCore3> core(player);
CComPtr<IWMPControls> controls;
core->get_controls(&controls);
CComPtr<IWMPPlaylist> playlist;
core->get_currentPlaylist(&playlist);
CComBSTR path("c:\\bar.mp3"); // alternatively http://foo/bar.mp3
```

The first approach to play something gives *"command not available"*:

```
core->put_url(path);
// ... waiting after that for WMP to load doesn't make a difference
controls->play(); // returns 0x000D1105 - NS_S_WMPCORE_COMMAND_NOT_AVAILABLE
```

The second approach only produces `S_OK`s, but nothing is actually played:

```
CComPtr<IWMPMedia> media;
core->newMedia(path, &media);
playlist->appendItem(media);
controls->playItem(media); // returns S_OK, but doesn't play
```

Another thing i noted is that `core->get_playState()` always returns `wmposMediaOpening`, no matter how long i wait.

I've stumbled upon one thread that suggests multi-threading might not work properly with WMP and this code runs in a multi-threaded apartment. Might that be the problem?
If not, what else could be preventing WMP from playing the files?

*Notable background:*
The WMP instance is created in a DLL with a browser as the host-process.

*Update:*
Trying plain DirectShow, which WMP should be using itself, exhibits a more specific problem - see the [question for that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1963241/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After [further investigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1963241/), it turned out that this was actually caused by a VS2005 workaround for VS2008s `AtlSetPerUserRegistration()` which was always active - but should have been only for the contained COM servers registration/unregistration.

The workaround overrides `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` with `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`, which obviously results in quite some components failing if they are created in-process.

Answer (score 3):

WMP supports two automation methods, embedded ActiveX or COM server.
For embedded use, you add the ActiveX via an object tag (execute some scripts via IHTMLWindow2 from your BHO/Band) or a hidden form and automate from there. See [Using the Windows Media Player Control in a Web Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd564581(VS.85).aspx) and [Hosting the Windows Media Player Control in a Windows Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd563023(VS.85).aspx) for sample codes.

For COM server use, just create the player as COM server and automate from it. 
You can either [make it a UI-less playback engine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd564579(VS.85).aspx), or [remote it so you have a full UI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd564264(VS.85).aspx).

Windows Media Player plays asynchronously, for example, it could call IMediaControl::Run and return immediately when you call put_URL (another immediate call to play would fail because it is already playing). If you do not need the automatic playing, I guess you need IWMPSettings::put_autoStart.

WMP assumes itself to be in the main thread. If you are in a worker thread or a MTA thread, I suggest you span another process to automate it, or remote it as an out-of-proc server.

Comment: Finally some feedback, thanks. I am trying to run it as an ui-less in-proc-COM-server. WMP gets created on the main thread and the put_URL() occurs there too. However, even waiting quite a while, querying the open state always results in `wmposMediaOpening` and it never starts to play (regardless wether i call `play()` or not). Any ideas on that?

Comment: I suggest you remote WMP and automate it in the same way to see if you get any message boxes.