# IGraphBuilder::RenderFile() failing with VFW_E_BAD_KEY - 0x800403f2

Tags: c++, windows, com, directshow

Continuing investigation on a [embedded WindowsMediaPlayer problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1935964/basic-playback-with-programmatically-created-windows-media-player), i am trying to do simple file playback via a DirectShow in-process server:

```
::CoInitializeEx(0, COINIT_MULTITHREADED);

CComPtr<IGraphBuilder> spGraph;
spGraph.CoCreateInstance(CLSID_FilterGraph, 0, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER);
CComQIPtr<IMediaControl> spMediaControl(spGraph);

// ... later:
spGraph->RenderFile(L"c:\\foo.wav", 0); // fails with VFW_E_BAD_KEY
spMediaControl->Run();
```

Interestingly, this runs fine on both systems i tested on (Windows XP 32 & x64) when doing it in a stand-alone application.
It however fails in my real use-case, a NPAPI based browser plugin - i.e. a DLL loaded into Firefox/Chrome/Opera.

Does anyone have an idea what could be going wrong here?
Or ideas on what else to try?

*Update:* also asked on the [Microsoft forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/windowsdirectshowdevelopment/thread/8eb3c3b4-f0d1-4aee-9e58-70bd892d879c).

*Update2:*
`IGraphBuilder::AddSourceFilter(path,path,&base)` already fails with the following registry calls (as seen in process monitor):

```
"RegOpenKey","HKCU\Software\Classes\c","NAME NOT FOUND","Desired Access: Query Value, Maximum Allowed" 
"RegOpenKey","HKCU\Software\Classes\Media Type\Extensions\.wav","NAME NOT FOUND","Desired Access: Read" 
"RegOpenKey","HKCU\Software\Classes\Media Type","NAME NOT FOUND","Desired Access: Read"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is reading the key from the wrong hive.  It should use HKLM, not HKCU.  The most likely reason for this is [registry virtualization.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa965884%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Comment: How can it be registry virtualization on Windows XP?

Comment: Actually, you solved it for me by making me think again about why it was mapped to HKCU - our VS2005 fallback for `AtlSetPerUserRegistration()` wasn't only activated for the contained com servers registration. Ouch.