# Is there a Windows Media Player API or Multimedia API in Windows

Tags: c++, windows, windows-media-player

I thought it would be fun to create an application that synchronizes few clients with a server to Play/Pause/Stop/Rewind/Forward or go to a given second of a movie on a existing (and running) Windows Media Player.

I googled for few hours to no avail. If that is the case, how are the multimedia keyboards (the ones with extra keys) managing to control WMP through their driver suite :O

I really want to keep it simple and I don't want to create WMP container application or something. Just a client application made in Qt that when receives a UDP packet would send Play/Pause or Stop signal to the player.

Further I could make my client application to wait until there is running WMP player.

Anyhow my question is ... do you guys have some tips or tricks on how should I do this or some resource to read the basics. I've never done something like that before and I don't really have much knowledge about process hooking and the likes. I really hope it doesn't come to that (*crosses fingers*). Please don't ask me why would I want to do something like that it's a really long story :) and it doesn't involve world domination in any way :P

P.S: As a finish I want to clarify. I'm aiming only Windows OS and only Windows Media Player. No other OS or multimedia player whatsoever. As I said, I would like to keep it simple :) Thank you in advance!

P.S: Security is not an issue since this application is only for my family

Comment: http://www.videolan.org/vlc/libvlc.html

Comment: Wouldn't that work only for VLC? :O My family doesn't like VLC :<

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1949176/62576