# IWMPCore destructor crash

Tags: c++, com, wmp

I'm trying to develop a c++ program to manipulate WMP libraries. Despite being new to WMP (and new to COM as well), I'm managing to do OK. But whatever I succeed in doing, my program always crashes at the end of main. Here's the minimal example:

```
#include "wmp.h"
#include "atlcomcli.h"
int main()
{
    CoInitialize(NULL);
    CComPtr<IWMPCore> spCore;
    HRESULT hr = ::CoCreateInstance(__uuidof(WindowsMediaPlayer),
                                    NULL,
                                    CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
                                    __uuidof(spCore),
                                    (void **) &spCore);
    spCore->close();      // Removing this doesn't help
    // spCore->Release(); // Doesn't compile: can't access private member
    CoUninitialize();
    return 0;
}
```

The crash occurs in atlcomcli.h:

```
~CComPtrBase() throw()
{
    if (p)
    p->Release(); // p has the value that was assigned to spCore
                  // read access fail flagged here
}
```

Please, can anyone tell me how to dispose of the IWMPCore interface?
(I'm using Visual Studio 2005, on Vista)

Comment: `CComPtr` destructor runs, and calls `Release()` on underlying dumb pointer, after you've already called `CoUninitialize`. This is illegal. Add `spCore.Release()` (note `.`, not `->`) before `CoUninitialize`, or else a pair of braces so that `CComPtr` lives in a smaller scope.

Comment: I found some maybe useful to you link about this and Visual Studio 2005 in particular. [check it]{http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1935964/basic-playback-with-programmatically-created-windows-media-player}

Comment: The question and the linked duplicate are related to different APIs , however share the same problem: leaving COM activity after `CoUninitilize` call.

Comment: @Igor Thanks for the perfect answer!

Comment: @RareFever Thanks a lot. This looks like it will save me some problems down the road.

Comment: @Roman Sorry! To mix a metaphor, when you're all at sea, it's difficult to see the wood for the trees.